# Scaling around center without viewBox?

Tags: svg, scale, center

I know much has been debated about this but i would like to know if there is a way to scale an element around its center without using viewBox (which, as far as i have learnt, must be applied to the svg, and not to a single object). In this exercise i am working on to understand the logic of svg scaling i would like the (invisible) red circle to appear and then to scale (as if it popped up) when you click on the yellow rect. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   id="star"
   x="170px"
   y="385px"
   width="100px"
   height="100px"
   xml:space="preserve"
   inkscape:version="0.48.5 r10040"
   sodipodi:docname="Exercise n.1.svg"><metadata
   id="metadata17"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
       rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
         rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /><dc:title /></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
   id="defs15" /><sodipodi:namedview
   pagecolor="#ffffff"
   bordercolor="#666666"
   borderopacity="1"
   objecttolerance="10"
   gridtolerance="10"
   guidetolerance="10"
   inkscape:pageopacity="0"
   inkscape:pageshadow="2"
   inkscape:window-width="1366"
   inkscape:window-height="705"
   id="namedview13"
   showgrid="false"
   inkscape:zoom="2.36"
   inkscape:cx="-22.881356"
   inkscape:cy="50"
   inkscape:window-x="-8"
   inkscape:window-y="-8"
   inkscape:window-maximized="1"
   inkscape:current-layer="star" />
    
<rect
   style="fill:#ffcc00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
   id="yelrect"
   width="33.050846"
   height="30.084745"
   x="14.457626"
   y="25.847458"
   ry="1.6126924" />
<path
   sodipodi:type="arc"
   style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;opacity:0"
   id="redcircle"
   sodipodi:cx="70.338982"
   sodipodi:cy="15.466102"
   sodipodi:rx="9.3220339"
   sodipodi:ry="8.2627115"
   d="m 79.661016,15.466102 a 9.3220339,8.2627115 0 1 1 -18.644068,0 9.3220339,8.2627115 0 1 1 18.644068,0 z"
   transform="matrix(0.96545455,0,0,1.0892308,1.1926041,24.577574)" />
 <animateTransform
     id="redcircle_anim1"
     xlink:href="#redcircle"
     attributeName="transform"
    type="scale"
     begin="yelrect.click"
     by="1"
     dur="1s"
     fill="freeze" />
 <animate
     id="redcircle_anim2"
     xlink:href="#redcircle"
     attributeName="opacity"
     begin="redcircle_anim1.begin"
     from="0"
    to="1"
     dur="1s"
     fill="freeze" />
</svg>
```

Comment: You can nest svg elements and put viewBox attributes on the nested svg elements if you want.

Comment: Thank you Robert Longson. Could you be so kind to show me how nesting another svg can do the trick in this example? Sorry but i am new to this and seems i cannot do it myself. I managed to move the red circle via another nested svg, but it still moves when scaling.

Comment: I don't really know what you want to do. I simply corrected your mistaken asumption in your first bracketed sentence.

Comment: Could you please scale the redcircle so that it maintains its center point?

Comment: I see no red circle, just a yellow square.

Comment: There's a id="redcircle" with opacity set to "0" marked as path

Answer (score 0):

When you scale an element, you scale not only its size, but also its position. As you have seen.

There are various ways to implement the solution, but the general principle behind them all is that the circle has to be scaled around it's own origin, and not that of the SVG (which is the top-left).

One way, is to effectively put the circle in it's own coordinate space, by shifting the responsibility of positioning of it to a parent group.

```
<g transform="translate(31,20)">
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" ... />
</g>
```

So now, as far as the circle is concerned, it is at the origin (0,0).  When you scale it with the animation, it scales around the origin - and thus doesn't move.  However its final position is still determined by the translation transform of its parent group.

```html
<svg id="star" width="100px" height="100px">
    
<rect
   style="fill:#ffcc00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none"
   id="yelrect"
   width="33.050846"
   height="30.084745"
   x="14.457626"
   y="25.847458"
   ry="1.6126924" />
<g transform="translate(31,20)">
  <ellipse cx="0" cy="0" rx="9.3220339" ry="8.2627115"
           style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;opacity:0"
           id="redcircle" />
</g>

<animateTransform
     id="redcircle_anim1"
     xlink:href="#redcircle"
     attributeName="transform"
    type="scale"
     begin="yelrect.click"
     by="1"
     dur="1s"
     fill="freeze" />
<animate
     id="redcircle_anim2"
     xlink:href="#redcircle"
     attributeName="opacity"
     begin="redcircle_anim1.begin"
     from="0"
    to="1"
     dur="1s"
     fill="freeze" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Paul LeBeau, this clarified and solved the problem!